# Save variables, collections, in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

How can I save variables, collections, dictionaries in vb.net so that after the user restart the software the modifications will be saved.

for Example through a textbox the user enters a new/old key and a value that changes a dictionary. After he restarts when he checks back the previously entered key, his modifications are permanent.

Comment: You will need to find *some* way to store the values: file, database, local settings, ...

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I used to ask the same question, seeing that you sound like an absolute beginner, I'll go easy.

Click `Project` on the top of the screen and scroll down to your program's properties. In my case it was   `Personal Assistant properties...`
[image]
Now click on the highlighted text, `Settings`
[image]
You should see a menu like this, now you can make new settings here. These are like variables but stay like that even when the program is restarted. In my case, I made one called Name for the program to remember the user's name.

If you want to use the setting, type **This** in: `My.Settings.[Name of setting]`
If you want to change it just put an equal sign after it and type in its new value. `My.Settings.[Name of setting] = [New Value]`

Here is an example:
    `Label1.Text = "Hello " + My.Settings.Name + "!"`

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are talking about a client application that stores this data locally? In that case isolated storage is a possibility, see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6535/Isolated-Storage-in-NET-to-store-application-data. Or you could have a local database based on SQLite to store these kinds of things.

You can also choose to store this data centrally. But we don't know your exact requirements/restrictions, you might want to give us some more information.